# Class cast exception - TextView cannot be casted to ImageView

Tags: java, android

I could not get why I am getting the class cast exception as I am only assigning the Imageview to Imageview but it states that can't cast the ImageView to TextView.

Below is the code for my xml and Activity class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/review_tbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toi_lbl"
                android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:text="Times Of India :"
                android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toi_txt"
                android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/star"
                android:textDirection="firstStrong" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imdb_lbl"
                android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:text="Imdb.com :"
                android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imdb_txt"
                android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/star"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:textDirection="firstStrong" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/in_lbl"
                android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:text="In.com :"
                android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/in_txt"
                android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/star"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
                android:textDirection="firstStrong" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movieName_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Ranjhana"
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"

         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reldate_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movieName_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Released On : 12 June 2013"
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/starring_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reldate_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Cast : Sonam Kapoor,Dhanush"
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/director_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/starring_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Director : Koi Hai"
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/producer_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/director_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Producer : Koi Hai"
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" />

  <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a151e2b670cd233"
        android:layout_below="@+id/producer_txt"

        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/producer_txt"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:text=" Raanjhanaa is an upcoming 2013 Hindi romance film, directed by Anand L. Rai and written by Himanshu Sharma. The film is produced by Krishika Lulla under the banner Eros International. The film stars Tamil film actor Dhanush in his Bollywood debut and Sonam Kapoor in the lead roles.[2] The film is scheduled to release on June 21, 2013 along with a dubbed Tamil version called Ambikapathy"
            android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" />
    </ScrollView>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_btn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/movieName_txt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movieName_txt"
        android:onClick="shareIt"
        android:src="@drawable/shareicon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my activity :

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.film_detail);

         ImageView movieImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

I am getting exception on this line.

```
 ImageView movieImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Thanks,
Amandeep

Comment: Try to clean your project and then run.

Comment: Can you post some more code of your java file ?

Comment: I really doubt if you get an exception there. Post the logcat and also, post the exact coode. Do not change anything before posting the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/star"
                android:textDirection="firstStrong" />
```

You have given the id as txt1 in this ImageView

Answer (score 1):

You have  `android:id="@+id/txt1"` in your `.xml` file which is associated with `ImageView` & with `TextView` as well, you should assign different **id** for  both of the views.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've the same id (`txt1`)

```
android:id="@+id/txt1"
```

for both an `ImageView` and `TextView` in your xml. Change the `ImageView` to something else(cuz honestly, `txt1` doesn't suit as an id of an ImageView).

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/txt1" // my id is txt1
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/star"
android:textDirection="firstStrong" />
....
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt1" // gosh, my id is txt1 too. :(
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/star"
android:gravity="center"
android:text=""
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/titlebackgroundcolor"
android:textDirection="firstStrong" />
```

Comment: But as he is using `ImageView` which contains the `id` `R.id.imageView1` so its should not throw error.

Comment: Look at his xml code fully. There is an `ImageView` in the first `TableLayout`  which has the same id.

Comment: I have checked already he has 3 views which contains the same id but in his java file as he has shown he has not used the view which contains the id `txt1`.

Comment: The OP may have shown either a wrong piece of code, or the place where the exception is thrown. I don't see the logcat. Once that is posted, it'll be clear.